# How to add random numbers together

Tags: python, random

```
number_checker = 0  

for random_variables in range(1,11):  
    import random  
    random = random.randint(1,25)  
    print(random)  
    if random % 2 == 0:  
        print("This number is even")  
        even_numbers = number_checker + random  
    else:  
        print("This number is odd")  
        odd_numbers = number_checker + random    

print("")  
print("This is the sum of even numbers.")  
print(even_numbers)  
print("")  
print("This is the sum of odd numbers.")  
print(odd_numbers)
```

Comment: Don't put `import` inside a loop.

Comment: Don't use `random` as the name of a variable. It's overwriting the variable used to hold the module (that's probably why you needed to do it every time.

Comment: `random = random.randint(1,25)` You just overwrote the `random` imported package with a local variable of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be adding the random number to `even_numbers` or `odd_numbers`, not `number_checker`. Since `number_checker` never changes, you're simply setting `even_numbers` and `odd_numbers` to the last even and odd numbers produced in the loop.

```
import random

even_numbers = 0
odd_numbers = 0
for _ in range(1,11):
    r = random.randint(1,25)
    print(r)
    if r % 2 == 0:
        print("This number is even")
        even_numbers += r
    else:
        print("This number is odd")
        odd_numbers += r

print("")
print("This is the sum of even numbers.")
print(even_numbers)
print("")
print("This is the sum of odd numbers.")
print(odd_numbers)
```